# One variable not reaching the Spring controller

Tags: java, spring-4

I have following defined in my controller class and for some reason the `definition` value is not reaching the controller when I tried to make a request for the `addEmployeeDetails` webservice with the following parameters

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/addEmployeeDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addEmployeeDetails
    (
        @RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="") String name,
        @RequestParam(value="is_obsolete", defaultValue="0") Integer is_obsolete,
        @RequestParam(value="is_relationshiptype", defaultValue="0") Integer is_relationshiptype,
        @RequestParam(value="emp_id", defaultValue="0") Integer emp_id,
        @RequestParam(value="company_id", defaultValue="0") Integer company_id,
        @RequestParam(value="definition", defaultValue="") String definition
    ) 
    {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();

        logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        logger.info("addEmployeeDetails ws params : " + 
                    "name="+name+
                    ",is_obsolete="+is_obsolete+
                    ",is_relationshiptype="+is_relationshiptype+
                    ",emp_id="+emp_id+
                    ",company_id="+company_id+
                    ",definition="+definition
                    );

        System.out.println("Is Definition Printing?");
        System.out.println(definition);

        // Remaining code below
```

The logger I used doesn't shows anything for definition and shows all other parameters I used.

Similarly, the printout statement doesn't shows anything when I tried to print using `System.out.println(definition);`

Is there any reason why this could be happening?

I have around 40 web services defined in a similar manner and I haven't observed such phenomenon.

**Observation :**

I noticed one thing, when I was including the `definition` as a second parameter in making a request from `POSTMAN` client, it wasn't working. However, when I moved it at the bottom (following the exact order as mentioned above), it worked. Is it like I would have to pass the parameters in the order as defined in the controller class?

Comment: edit the default value of definition to know if you are passing the right param  @RequestParam(value="definition", defaultValue="default definition") String definition

Comment: @Touzene I tried doing that and in that case only default value is getting printed even if I am passing the right parameter while making my request. And it looks like the change of order doesn't matter which I mentioned in my observation above. For some reason it seems to be working only when I specify it as a last parameter. I am wondering why?

Comment: What's the URL to invoke the controller?

Comment: Your controller looks like it should work, I suspect that the parameter is not being set correctly when making the http request.

Comment: One thing I would like you consider is the purpose of the HTTP request types, a `GET` request is for the client to retrieve information from the server, this looks like you are using it for sending data, I would strongly suggest that you should change this to a `POST` or `PUT`.